# how to import corresponding data from another sheet on same workbook when I select a value from dropdown menu?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a workbook that contains two sheets.  In sheet one, I have a dropdown box that contains a list of soccer teams. Each dropdown box is in column A. In column B I have the heading "goals".

In sheet two I have a list of these soccer teams, with each team occupying a row in column A. In column B I have a number adjacent to each team name and this is called "goals scored".  For example, A2 is Arsenal and in B2 is 7 - meaning Arsenal scored 7 goals.

When I select Arsenal in my dropdown box in sheet one, how can I make the 7 import from sheet 2 cell B2 into column B on sheet 1?

Essentially, I want the number from "goals scored" in sheet 2 to import to sheet 1 whenever I select the corresponding team from my dropdown box.

Hopefully this makes sense!

Here is my data validation rules for sheet 1:

[Validation rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNQqj.png)

```
=Sheet3!$B$1:$B$22
```

I am unsure of how to link the cells to get my data across.

Comment: Use the formula xlookup for whatever is selected, or even vlookup.

Comment: Or use the `QUERY` function. it gives you more control over what data you pull and where it goes

Comment: thanks, these look helpful.  I will have to figure out the exact commands as I'm not very familiar with spreadsheets at all!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sheet that you can explore.

---> [Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SNjIC1LG9o8l2QDqumzjUL__BSRLxWfOOHR8sy3S5Uw/edit#gid=1667726391) <---

Use the "Validation Tab" to input your Team names and goals. I made up some mock team names that you can replace with your real names.

I included two different tabs with different formulas to use to solve this.

1. Query Formula Example
2. Index Formula Example

Another option is a vlookup() but I prefer Index matches because if you move the columns around, the index match will still work, if you use a Vlookup, you need to adjust your column reference number.

Check it out and let me know what you think! Make a copy if you'd like to edit.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron.  I have requested access to your sheet.  Jeff.

Comment: Provided access, but you should only need to make a copy to use your own.

Comment: @ubuntuuser- did that answer your question?